# What takes so long when toggling off the desktop? 

Tags: nautilus, gconf

What takes so long when toggling off the desktop?

(gconf-editor , then apps > nautilus > preference > show desktop toggle)

It's not that I can't do anything else in the meantime, but the pointer is in 'spin' mode.

Toggling back on does not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is simply a bug, as nautilus isn't doing anything.

If you restart nautilus (`killall nautilus`) the pointer will come out of 'spin' mode.